# What is the html code for "Edit item" to be use on form web part?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, button

I would like to have an edit button (not in ribbon) to show when a Sharepoint list item is viewed/display, with condition Where field "Status" is not equal to "Approved".  Can somebody lend a hand on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code with [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views),insert script editor webpart to list form and insert the script(update the list form URL to your own).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var CustomCtx = {};

    /**
     * Initialization
     */
    function init() {

        CustomCtx.OnPostRender = customDisplay;       

        // Register the custom template
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(CustomCtx);
    }

    /**
     * Rendering template
     */
    function customDisplay(ctx) {
        window.PostRunCheck;
        if(!window.PostRunCheck){
            var currentStatus = ctx.ListData.Items[0].Status;
            var currentItemID=parseInt(getQueryStringParameter('ID'));
            var htmlEdit = "<a href='/Lists/Tasks/EditForm.aspx?ID={{ID}}'>Edit</a><br/>";
            if (currentStatus != "Approved"){
                $('table.ms-formtable').parent().prepend(htmlEdit.replace('{{ID}}',currentItemID));
            }
            window.PostRunCheck=true;
        }

    }
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
            var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
            }
        }   
    // Run our intiialization
    init();

})();</script>
```

[image]